# CURL - use proxy certificate from memory

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I want to perform HTTPS connection with CURL through a proxy, and using in memory server certificates (CAINFO) - instead of loading them from files with `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and `CURLOPT_PROXY_CAINFO`. I see [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html) sample that loads certificates from memory instead of using `CURLOPT_CAINFO`, but I want to do the same also for proxy certificate instead of using `CURLOPT_PROXY_CAINFO`.

How do I use proxy certificate from memory?

Comment: What platform are you on? There's a trick you can use with pipes on *nix.

Comment: ... or mount your memory onto the filesystem (a la tmpfs)

Comment: Windows and Mac. If I add the proxy certificate into the in-memory list of server certificates as in the curl sample above, will it work and verify the proxy?

Comment: Try it and see. According to the documentation that function is called at the right time, yes.

Comment: I will try. my assumption was that proxy certificates are verified separately from server certificates since CURL provides 2 different options (CURLOPT_CAINFO and CURLOPT_PROXY_CAINFO) when working with CAINFO. are you saying that also when I work with certificate files I can use CURLOPT_CAINFO for proxy certificate?

Comment: No. Curl knows up front whether it is connecting to a proxy or to a real server. In both cases it creates an SSL context (which your linked answer modifies), then adds the respective CA certificate to that context's trust store, and only then makes the connection. What your linked answer thus does is effectively trusting that CA for both proxies and real servers. If you can live with that, the solution should work fine.